# Some parts of the Rails page doesn't render randomnly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using `Rails 3.2.11` and finding this weird issue.

When the page is rendered, header partial is displayed and even the footer is also displayed in the browser. And the `form/content` doesn't get rendered and shown blank.

If the page is refreshed then the whole page is displayed.

The weird thing is that it doesn't happen always. It happens rarely which I'm finding kinda lost to debug and its even hard to reproduce.

What might be wrong of how can I debug this weirdness?

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Is the form surrounded with `<%=  %>`? - Paste some code if you can...

Comment: It could be caching issue. You should post your code from layout.

Comment: Can you please post your code from routes as well as layouts..

Comment: Check your browser console/firebug error log and see if you get any hint.

Comment: Since its so random that pasting the code of some views won't make any sense coz when I do refresh, its there without any errors. Nothing error show in the firebug console too.